# Getting font with getResources().getAssets() from assets folder return NullPointerException

Tags: android

Im trying to load custome font from "assets\font" folder

this is my "*TypefaceSingelton*" class code :

```
    public class TypefaceSingelton {

        private static TypefaceSingelton instance = new TypefaceSingelton();

        private TypefaceSingelton() {}

        public static TypefaceSingelton getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }
        public static  Typeface getFont() {
            return Typeface.createFromAsset(AppContext.getAppContext().
            getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/Myfont.otf");
        }
    }
```

and my "*AppContext*" class :

```
public class AppContext extends Application {

    public static Context context;
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(){

        super.onCreate();
        AppContext.context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return AppContext.context;
    }
```

}

and how i use it inside my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final Typeface FontTF = TypefaceSingelton.getFont();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final AutoCompleteTextView CtextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        CtextView.setTypeface(FontTF);
```

and it gives exception at "Typeface.createFromAsset" inside TypefaceSingelton :

```
08-16 07:55:51.834: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 07:55:51.834: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):     at com.test.TypefaceSingelton.getFont(TypefaceSingelton.java:20)
08-16 07:55:51.834: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):     at com.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:133)
08-16 07:55:51.834: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-16 07:55:51.834: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
```

im going to use "TypefaceSingelton" to avoid performance drop

other than that program works with below code :

```
private final Typeface FontTF;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Typeface FontTF = TypefaceSingelton.getFont();
```

Comment: Check your manifest file if application name is AppContext:  `<application
        android:name="{packege}.AppContext" ... > ... </application>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
public static  Typeface getFont() {
            return Typeface.createFromAsset(AppContext.getAppContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/Myfont.otf");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Attention otf font is not support in Android. Just ttf font

Why not use a custom class TypefacedTextView whose extend AppCompatTextView and create styleable for add type face property

```
public class TypefacedTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

public TypefacedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypefacedTextView);
    String fontName = styledAttrs.getString(R.styleable.TypefacedTextView_typeface);
    setTypeFace(fontName);

    styledAttrs.recycle();
}

public void setTypeFace(String fontName){
    try{
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);

    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

And a styleable like this

```
 <declare-styleable name="TypefacedTextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

You add this styleable in the file attrs.xml in dir res/values